# Convert Jpeg to Blob images in order to insert them in SQLITE3

Tags: python

I would like to store my pictures into my sqlite database with python. How can I do that?
Here is my code, but it is not working:

```
import sqlite3
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect('images.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_bd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (foto BLOB);'

for i in os.listdir('\myphotos'):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabela (foto) VALUES (?);", i)
    conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Anyone could help me, please?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about why it isn't working? What error message do you get, or what part doesn't work?

Comment: It said:
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 23 supplied."
But have already made the suggested changes by jsbueno and now it shows:
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image_1.jpeg'!"
So, I really don't know what is happening.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store actual images in your database? That tends to make your database enormous to back up and make your images less accessible. How about just storing a reference to your images in the database so it stays lean and mean and you can still view and edit your images via the regular filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Using pathlib instead of `os.listdir`, it can become:

```
from pathlib import Path

mydir = Path("myphotos")

for image_path in Path("/myphotos").iterdir():

    ...
    if image_path.suffix.lower() in [".jpeg", ".jpg", ...]:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabela (foto) VALUES (?);", image_path.read_bytes()
    ...
```

Pathlib's iterdir already yields the full path for each file, not just the filename, and provide the `read_bytes` method: no need to open the file and call a method on the returned object.

Comment: however, note that this would be of very little use, since there is no other column on the same table by which you could select specific images - one would be limited to iterating through all image files - without even knowing their name: this puts the _image data_ in the table. the filename would need another column.

Comment: Thansk a lot, however it says "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.jpeg'" despite this image is right there.

Comment: That is because "i" is not the complete path for the file: just. make it be by concatenating the directory name. Use "os.path.join", or pathlib.Path

Comment: thanks a lot again. I'm new in Python, and unfortunatelly I don't know how to do that yet. How could I do it?

Comment: Now it says:
"AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only"
or:
"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"
It's getting harder being succefull in it.